# How to create an animation using Python folium on Map?

Tags: python, python-3.x, animation, maps, folium

I have two data sets one is Geodataset of road segments as follows
[Road segments data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZL6vp.png)

second is average speed on that road segment for a year.

[Speed on the road segments](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WbhnJ.png)

I need to create an animation according to the speed on that segment like red, green, yellow like the traffic shown on google maps. Please help.

I tried creating feature but it isn't working.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: e.g do you want an animation whichs shows avg speeds day by day or just the roads colored by their avg speed overall ?